# String doesn't seem to overwrite .csv file. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, csv, nsstring

I've been writing a simple app drawing innitial values in from a .csv file, then adding to them and then trying to write the modified data back out to the same CSV file. The output in the terminal window suggests its working ok, but when I look at the file or access it from another boot (I'm testing this on Xcode's iPhone simulator), it doesn't seem to work. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)AddButtonPressed:(id)sender{

// Get the input from the input field and add it to the sum in the bank field
float a = ([input.text floatValue]);
float b = a+([earned.text floatValue]);

// adding the old value of 'earned' text field to the value from the input field and update the interface 
earned.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%4.2f",b];

// THIS IS THE BEGINNINGS OF THE CODE FOR WRITING OUT TO A .CSV FILE SO THAT DATA CAN BE USED LATER IN EXCEL
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Income" ofType:@"csv"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSLog(@"found it");
    NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"string looks like this\: %@", contents);

    //set the contents of income to be the same as what's currently in income.csv
    [income setString:contents];
    NSLog(@"income contains\: %@", income);



    //NEXT Apend income to add NSDATE, Textinput and the float value 'a'

    //Get the Date...
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];

    //... And apend it into a readable string with a comma on the end
    NSString *theDate = [[NSString alloc] init];
    theDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d.%d", day,month,year];
    NSLog(@"The Date is %@", theDate);


    //holder string till I get the text input wired up in the interface
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc]init];
    text = @"filler words";

    //turn the float entered in the GUI to a string ready for adding to the 'income' mutable array
    NSString *amountAdded = [[NSString alloc]init];
    amountAdded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.2f", a];

    //format the final string and pass it to our 'income' NSMutable Array
    NSString *finalString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@, %@, %@", theDate, text, amountAdded];
    NSLog(@"final string is %@", finalString);
    [income appendString:finalString];
    NSLog(@"income now reads %@", income);

    [income writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];



    NSLog(@"completed writing to income.csv which now reads %@", contents);

}
else{
    NSLog(@"not a sausage");
}
```

Comment: What is "income" i don't see where you declare/initialize that object, also you could try NSError* error; [income writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; and check if there was an error there with in the error object.

Comment: income is a NSMustableString initialised in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bneely's suggestion of passing in a non-nil error pointer is useful for debugging system calls that take an error parameter.

It looks to me like you are reading CSV file from the bundle, modifying the data, and trying to save the data back to the file in the bundle. The bundle is read-only in iOS. (Beware, though, that the simulator does not enforce this. Last time I checked you could write to your app bundle on the sim, but it fails on a device.

You will need to write code that copies your CSV file from the bundle into your documents directory on launch if it doesn't exist. Then fall into the code that opens the CSV file (in documents) modifies the data, and writes it back.

That way the first time launching the app after install, the CSV file gets copied from the bundle to documents. After that all operations on the file take place on the copy in documents, and you don't overwrite the file if it already exists.

Comment: Could you tell me if is the best place to put this in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the delegate?

Comment: Yes, the check to see if the file exists/copy the file from the bundle from documents would go in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your app delegate

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` with nil instead of a valid NSError reference. If the method is returning an error, you won't know about it.

On the line before `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`, insert this line

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

Now change `error:nil` to `error:&error`. Then add this block below it:

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"writeToFile error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Run your code again and see if you are getting an error writing the file.